# Placing custom labels under a slider wpf

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-style

My problem is straight forward I want to have some labels underneath the Slider control. I have found some interesting solutions online especially this one 
[Labels under slider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29792801/wpf-slider-tick-label)
 asking to edit the Thumb but I am not able to get it working when I use the style it gives so many scribbles underneath the Data.

I have also been trying to play with the template in the blend. I was able to change the colors of the Ticks in the Slider but when I place textblock with some text my expectation is it would repeat the labels based on the number of Ticks but I see a single textblock.

Can anyone help me with the style posted in the link or even edit my style. Here is the code I have so far.

```
<ControlTemplate
            x:Key="SliderHorizontal"
            TargetType="{x:Type Slider}">
            <Border
                x:Name="border"
                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition
                            Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition
                            Height="Auto"
                            MinHeight="{TemplateBinding MinHeight}" />
                        <RowDefinition
                            Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition
                            Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TickBar
                        x:Name="TopTick"
                        Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                        Height="4"
                        Margin="0,0,0,2"
                        Placement="Top"
                        Grid.Row="0"
                        Visibility="Collapsed" />
                    <TickBar
                        x:Name="BottomTick"
                        Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                        Height="4"
                        Margin="0,2,0,0"
                        Placement="Bottom"
                        Grid.Row="2"
                        Visibility="Collapsed" />
                    <TextBlock
                        x:Name="tblSomething"
                        Text="Hello"
                        Grid.Row="3" Foreground="Black"
                        ></TextBlock>
                    <Border
                        x:Name="TrackBackground"
                        BorderBrush="{StaticResource SliderThumb.Track.Border}"
                        BorderThickness="1"
                        Background="{StaticResource SliderThumb.Track.Background}"
                        Height="4.0"
                        Margin="5,0"
                        Grid.Row="1"
                        VerticalAlignment="center">
                        <Canvas
                            Margin="-6,-1">
                            <Rectangle
                                x:Name="PART_SelectionRange"
                                Fill="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"
                                Height="4.0"
                                Visibility="Hidden" />
                        </Canvas>
                    </Border>
                    <Track
                        x:Name="PART_Track"
                        Grid.Row="1">
                        <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                            <RepeatButton
                                Command="{x:Static Slider.DecreaseLarge}"
                                Style="{StaticResource RepeatButtonTransparent}" />
                        </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                        <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                            <RepeatButton
                                Command="{x:Static Slider.IncreaseLarge}"
                                Style="{StaticResource RepeatButtonTransparent}" />
                        </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                        <Track.Thumb>
                            <Thumb
                                x:Name="Thumb"
                                Focusable="False"
                                Height="18"
                                OverridesDefaultStyle="True"
                                Template="{StaticResource SliderThumbHorizontalDefault}"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                Width="11" />
                        </Track.Thumb>
                    </Track>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger
                    Property="TickPlacement"
                    Value="TopLeft">
                    <Setter
                        Property="Visibility"
                        TargetName="TopTick"
                        Value="Visible" />
                    <Setter
                        Property="Template"
                        TargetName="Thumb"
                        Value="{StaticResource SliderThumbHorizontalTop}" />
                    <Setter
                        Property="Margin"
                        TargetName="TrackBackground"
                        Value="5,2,5,0" />
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger
                    Property="TickPlacement"
                    Value="BottomRight">
                    <Setter
                        Property="Visibility"
                        TargetName="BottomTick"
                        Value="Visible" />
                    <Setter
                        Property="Fill"
                        TargetName="BottomTick"
                        Value="Orange" />
                    <Setter
                        Property="Template"
                        TargetName="Thumb"
                        Value="{StaticResource SliderThumbHorizontalBottom}" />
                    <Setter
                        Property="Margin"
                        TargetName="TrackBackground"
                        Value="5,0,5,2" />
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger
                    Property="TickPlacement"
                    Value="Both">
                    <Setter
                        Property="Visibility"
                        TargetName="TopTick"
                        Value="Visible" />
                    <Setter
                        Property="Visibility"
                        TargetName="BottomTick"
                        Value="Visible" />
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger
                    Property="IsSelectionRangeEnabled"
                    Value="true">
                    <Setter
                        Property="Visibility"
                        TargetName="PART_SelectionRange"
                        Value="Visible" />
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger
                    Property="IsKeyboardFocused"
                    Value="true">
                    <Setter
                        Property="Foreground"
                        TargetName="Thumb"
                        Value="Blue" />
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
```